# PGSQL: How to find Bank ending balace by recent statement date according each customer

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called "bankStatement" where we have `bankaccount_id`, `statement_date`,`begining_balance` and `ending_balance` as columns. My requirement is to find the ending balance of all `bankaccount_id` using recent `statement_date`. Lets say for example

```
bankaccount_id  statement_date  begining_balance  ending_balance
--------------  -------------   ----------------  --------------
   101            05-05-16       1500              1000
   101            10-05-16       1000              2000
   101            06-06-16       2000               500
```

Now i need to get 06-06-16 th of ending balance as 500, but when i tried

```
select bankaccount_id,max(statement_date),ending_balance from bankStatement
group by bankaccount_id,ending_balance
```

it gives all the record because of grouping by `ending_balance`. How to sort out this to get the final ending balance. So the result should be like this,

```
bankaccount_id  statement_date  ending_balance
--------------  -------------   ---------------- 
     101            06-06-16        500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Postgres' **distinct on** extension:

```
select 
  distinct on (bankaccount_id) 
  bankaccount_id, statement_date, ending_balance 
from 
  bankstatement 
order by 
  bankaccount_id, statement_date desc
```

In my opinion this approach is more elegant and safer than subselecting with the max (what if two records share the same timestamp?).

Comment: thanks for your support... it is so simple and works charm...cool

Answer (score 1):

Find the max statement date in a subquery and then get all the original information for that account and statement date.

```
select bs.bankaccount_id,
    bs.statement_date,
    bs.ending_balance 
from bankStatement bs
join (select bankaccount_id, 
          max(statement_date) max_statement_date 
      from bankStatement 
      group by  bankaccount_id) max
    on bs.bankaccount_id=max.bankaccount_id
        and bs.statement_date = max.max_statement_date
```